# Create an assembly from a class object to be saved and used at later stage

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I'm trying to figure out how to save a class object as an assembly, so that I can save that assembly to a local location etc to be used at at a later stage

Example the test class created, I'd like to create an assembly of it after in was instantiated.

```cs
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test newtest = new test("someInfo");
            //Create assembly from tt
            Assembly newAssem = NewAssembly.CreateAssembly(tt);
        }
    }


    public class test
    {
        public string val {get ;set;}
        public test(string v)
        {
            val = v;
        }
    }    
}
```

So then in this method I want to create the assembly

```cs
public static class NewAssembly
{
    public static Assembly CreateAssembly(test tt)
    {
        Assembly _proxyAssembly;
        CodeDomProvider _codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CS");
        CodeCompileUnit _codeCompileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
        string _proxyCode;

        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            CodeGeneratorOptions codeGenOptions = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
            codeGenOptions.BracingStyle = "C";
            _codeDomProvider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(_codeCompileUnit, writer, codeGenOptions);
            writer.Flush();
            _proxyCode = writer.ToString();
        }

        CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
        compilerParams.OutputAssembly = "some local path \\aName.dll";

        CompilerResults results;

        results = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams,_proxyCode);

        _proxyAssembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
        return _proxyAssembly;
    }
}
```

That was the best examples I've been able to get together but I'm not sure if its correct and also don't know what I'm missing like where the actual class gets added and how to finish the method.

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: _"how to save a class [instance] as an assembly, so that I can save that assembly to a local location etc to be used at at a later stage"_ - **why?** It seems you could benefit from using resources or serialization, rather than what you're trying to do here. Please explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Also note that assemblies don't hold type *instances* (like `newtest` in your post), but *types* (classes: `test`). It sounds like what you really want is serialization, as @CodeCaster wrote.

Comment: So you guys saying one can't create an assembly of an instantiated class with its current values for it to be used at a later stage. I first tried to use XMLSerializer but ran into an issue where the actual class object I tried to serialize contained a ref to a sealed class